# A Matrix Integral Equation

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, integral-equations, matrix-calculus

We have an integral equation on matrix.

${\Im(t)}=\Im(0)+\int_{0}^{t} \Im(s)[K(s)]_{ \times  }ds \tag 1$

1. $[\hspace{.2cm} ]_{\times}$ is skew symmetric matrix with diagonals zero and is non invertible. $[\hspace{.2cm} ]_{\times}$ is defined as follows if $P= \left(\begin{array}{c}x \\ y \\ z \end{array}\right)$ then    $[P ]_{\times}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
      0 & -z  & y  \\
      z  & 0 & -x  \\
     -y  & x  & 0 \\
      \end{array} \right)$
2. $ K(t)=(1-t)\left(\begin{array}{c}a_0\\ b_0\\ c_0\end{array}\right)+t\left(\begin{array}{c}a_1\\ b_1\\ c_1\end{array}\right)$, $a_i,b_i,c_i$ ($i=0,1$) are constants.
3. $\Im(t)$ is a $3\times 3$ rotational matrix ($\det(\Im(t))=1, \Im(t)^T\Im(t)=I$).

**Question**

Can we solve  $\Im(t)$ (invertible) from given constants and $\Im(0)$ ? Thanks for taking time to read this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen the notation $[]_{\times }$ before. More standard is to use
the Levi-Civita pseudo-tensor $\mathbf{\varepsilon }=\{\varepsilon
_{klm}\}$, $\varepsilon _{klm}$ is odd under the interchange of any two
subscripts and $\varepsilon _{klm}=1$ for $klm=123$ and all even
permutations of $123$. Then, with
\begin{equation*}
P=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}
\right) =\mathbf{x},
\end{equation*}
we have
\begin{equation*}
\lbrack P]_{\times }=-\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot x}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{J}(t)[\mathbf{K}(t)]_{\times }=-\mathbf{J}(t)\mathbf{\cdot
\varepsilon \cdot K}(t)=\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot K}(t)\}\mathbf{\cdot J}%
(t)=\mathbf{K}(t)\times \mathbf{J}(t).
\end{equation*}
Thus
\begin{equation*}
\partial _{t}\mathbf{J}(t)=\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot K}(t)\}\mathbf{\cdot J
}(t)=\mathbf{K}(t)\times \mathbf{J}(t).
\end{equation*}
Dotting with $\mathbf{J}(t)$ we see that $\mathbf{J}(t)\mathbf{\cdot }
\partial _{t}\mathbf{J}(t)=0$ so $\mathbf{J}(t)^{2}$ is conserved. \ Next we
write
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{J}(t) &=&\mathsf{U}(t,0)\mathbf{\cdot J}(0). \\
\partial _{t}\mathsf{U}(t,s) &=&\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot K}(t)\}\mathbf{
\cdot }\mathsf{U}(t,s).
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot K}(t_{1})$ and $\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot K}%
(t_{2})$ commute,
\begin{equation*}
\mathsf{U}(t,s)=\exp [\int_{s}^{t}du\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot K}(u)]
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{K}(u) &=&(1-u)\mathbf{k}_{1}+u\mathbf{k}_{2} \\
\int_{0}^{t}du\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot K}(u) &=&\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot }%
\{\mathbf{k}_{1}t+\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{k}_{2}-\mathbf{k}_{1})t^{2}\}=\mathbf{%
\varepsilon \cdot L}(t).
\end{eqnarray*}
Next
\begin{equation*}
\mathsf{U}(t,0)=\exp [\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)]=\mathsf{I}+\mathbf{
\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)+\frac{1}{2!}\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)\}^{2}+
\frac{1}{3!}\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)\}^{3}\cdots
\end{equation*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\varepsilon _{klm}L_{m}\varepsilon _{lrs}L_{s} &=&-\varepsilon
_{lkm}\varepsilon _{lrs}L_{m}L_{s}=-\{\delta _{kr}\delta _{ms}-\delta
_{ks}\delta _{mr}\}L_{m}L_{s}=-\delta _{kr}L^{2}+L_{k}L_{r} \\
\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)\}^{2} &=&-\mathsf{I}L^{2}+\mathbf{LL} \\
\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)\}^{3} &=&\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}
(t)\}\mathbf{\cdot }\{-\mathsf{I}L^{2}+\mathbf{LL}\}=-L^{2}\mathbf{
\varepsilon \cdot L}(t) \\
\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)\}^{4} &=&-L^{2}\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot
L}(t)\}^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\exp [\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)] &=&\mathsf{I}+(1-\frac{L^{2}}{3!}
+\cdots )\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)+(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{4!}
L^{2}+\cdots )\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)\}^{2} \\
&=&\mathsf{I}+\frac{1}{L}(\sin L)\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)-\frac{1}{
L^{2}}(\cos L-1)\{\mathbf{\varepsilon \cdot L}(t)\}^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
where
\begin{equation*}
L(t)^{2}=\{\mathbf{k}_{1}t+\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{k}_{2}-\mathbf{k}
_{1})t^{2}\}^{2}.
\end{equation*}
Thus we obtain $\mathsf{U}(t,0)$ and hence $\mathbf{J}(t)$ but the solution
does not look simple.

Answer (score 0):

Spontaneously I'd say take the derivative on both sides to get rid of the integral. The equation reduces to $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} I(t)  = I(t) \left[K(t) \right]_x$. So if $I(t) = [v_1,v_2,v_3](t), v_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and $I(t) K(t)_x = [u_1,u_2,u_3](t)$, then for all $t$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}v_i(t) = u_i(t)$ must hold. So you can already simplify the problem by casting it into a set of coupled differential equations of the form $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(v_1,v_2,v_3)^T = $ something. Now you can find that something by noting that if $K(t) = [L_1,L_2,L_3](t)$, and each $L_i = (L_{i,1},L_{i,2},L_{i,3})^T$, then each $v_i$ satisfies:

$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} v_i = L_{i,1} v_1 + L_{i,1} v_2 + L_{i,3}v_3$.

Cast all of these identities into one matrix equation, i.e. $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} v = A v$ with $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)^T$. Now you have basically casted the problem into the form $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} v(t) = A(t) v(t)$. Whether or not you can find a solution depends on $A(t)$.

Comment: Actually that A(t) is our $[K(t)]_{\times}$..It is  I made to this form from there..Thanks for the effort

Comment: No, if $\left[[K(t)]_x \right]_{ij} = L_{ij}$ then  $A(t) = \begin{pmatrix} L_{11} I & L_{12} I & L_{13} I \\ L_{21} I & L_{22} I & L_{23} I \\ L_{31} I & L_{32} I & L_{33} I \end{pmatrix}$, where $I$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix.